# Nodejs Websocket connection in an ES6 class

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, websocket, callback

I am not sure if this is the correct way to implement a websocket connection in NodeJS, but the problem I am having is not with WebSockets but with class variables.

This is my WebSocketClass:

```
class WebSocketCalss { 

    constructor ( httpserver )
    {
        console.log("Initializing WebSocketCalss");
        this.httpServer = httpserver;
        this.connection = null;
        this.client = null;
        this.initializeWebSocket();
    }

    initializeWebSocket()
    {
        var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;

        var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
            httpServer: this.httpServer
        });

        wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
            console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + '.');
            this.connection = request.accept(null, request.origin); 
            console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
            this.connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({ type: "history", data: "data"} ));
            var t = 0;

            /* ---- Client ---- */
            var W3CWebSocket = require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;
            this.client = new W3CWebSocket('wss://ws.bitstamp.net');

            this.client.onerror = function() {
                console.log('Connection Error');
            };

            this.client.onopen = function() {
                console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
                var subscribeMsg = {
                    "event": "bts:subscribe",
                    "data": {
                        "channel": "live_trades_btcusd"
                    }
                };
                this.client.send(JSON.stringify(subscribeMsg));
            };

            this.client.onclose = function() {
                console.log('echo-protocol Client Closed');
            };

            this.client.onmessage = function(e) {
                if (typeof e.data === 'string') {
                    var bitstampPrice = JSON.parse(e.data).data.price;
                    console.log(bitstampPrice);

                    this.connection.sendUTF(bitstampPrice);
                }
            };
            });



        //this.connection.sendUTF(JSON.stringify({ type: "history", data: "data"} ));
    }

}

module.exports = (httpserver) => { return new WebSocketCalss(httpserver) }
```

It maybe hairy, so this is what I am trying to do:

- My NodeJS server will open a WebSocket connection to my client (browser)
- In this WebSocket, I want to send a value that is received from another WebSocket (that is, my NodeJS will connect as a client)
- Things seem to work fine individually, however, when I try to send the value (that I received as a client), to my own client (as I am the server), I get

> Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Basically, inside the callback, the this variable are not defined. It is as if this is a new object.
I am not familiar with ES6 so I believe I am doing something fundamentally wrong.
If anyone could shed some light in to this that'd be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `this` inside a `function()`, the context of the `this` is bound to the `function` and not the outside class.

```
this.client.onopen = () => {
    console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
    var subscribeMsg = {
        "event": "bts:subscribe",
        "data": {
            "channel": "live_trades_btcusd"
        }
    };
    this.client.send(JSON.stringify(subscribeMsg));
};
```

Comment: Thank you Faizuddin. In this case, what do you think is the best way to retain the original "this.connection" object in the callback?

Comment: There's a simple way: assign the `this` of the class to a variable like `self` before writing the function and then use the `self` inside the `onopen` callback.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me where in the code I should assign self to this?

Comment: Just before the `onopen` callback where this is still bound to the `class`

Comment: Thank you. In that case it should be before `.on` because `'onopen` is inside of that. Is that correct?